# perl: sh: 1: Syntax error: Bad fd number

Tags: perl

I have a very simple Perl script that fails with this error message:

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: Bad fd number
```

Here is the script (two lines)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
system("xterm >& /dev/null &");
```

If I run the same xterm command from the command-line, it works.  From the Perl script, it doesn't.  What is wrong?

Comment: I don't see how that hit answers my question.  That guy wasn't running a Perl script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
system(EXPR)
```

is short for<sup>[1]</sup>

```
system("/bin/sh", "-c", EXPR)
```

In other words, it takes a bourne shell command.

```
xterm >& /dev/null &
```

isn't a valid bourne shell command. You want

```
xterm >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Maybe you used a different shell when you tested it outside of Perl.

---

1. Technically, it's closer to

   ```
   use Config qw( );
   system($Config::Config{sh}, "-c", EXPR)
   ```

   Except in Windows.

Comment: Is that fairly new with Perl?  The "xterm >& /dev/null &" works fine with Perl 5.10.

Comment: If I put system("set < LOG_SET") in a PERL script, then grep for SHELL in the output file LOG_SET, it says: SHELL='/bin/tcsh'.  From that, I assumed that system() starts a tsch shell.  How did I go wrong?

Comment: @JB_User That prints out the `$SHELL` environment variable, which is the user's preferred shell. That does not mean that it is used by `system`. In fact, POSIX `system` is specified to always use `sh`.

Comment: Okay, well I guess I'm just trying to figure out why my script works on some systems, but not others.

Comment: Re "*Is that fairly new with Perl?*", No, `system` has always used `/bin/sh` (except on Windows)

Comment: Re "*in a PERL script*", The name of the language is "Perl".

Comment: Re "*How did I go wrong?*", Instead of reading the documentation, you assumed `system EXPR` used the `SHELL` env var. It doesn't. It wouldn't make any sense for `system EXPR` to use the `SHELL` env var since the programmer wouldn't know for which shell to write.

Comment: Okay.  What part of documentation explains why my original script works on one machine, but not another.  I'm happy to read.

Comment: @JB_User, That wasn't the question you asked, but my answer also does answer that question:  It behaved differently on the two machines because `/bin/sh` behaved differently.

Comment: Okay, thanks for helping out with this.  I think I full understand what was happening.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the preferred syntax for redirecting both stdout and stderr in Bash is `&>`, not `>&`, because the latter can be confused with other redirection forms.

Secondly, `system` uses `/bin/sh` which may behave differently than your default shell.

Try writing it out explicitly, as in

```
system("xterm >/dev/null 2>&1 &");
```

or skipping the shell altogether.

```
if (fork() == 0) {
    open STDOUT, '>', '/dev/null';
    open STDERR, '>&', *STDOUT;
    exec "xterm";
    POSIX::_exit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers.  I did get it working.  Now I'm trying to figure out why my original script works on some systems, but not others.

Comment: @JB_User Because `/bin/sh` is not the same everywhere. Some common Linux distros use Dash and others use Bash. BSDs mostly use ash.

Comment: Is there a simple way to tell, beforehand, whether my original script will work?  Dash, Bash, or Ash?  I don't even know what they are.  There's no wikipedia page for Dash.

Comment: @JB_User, Perl executes `/bin/sh -c command`. You can do the same. But you'll need to quote `command` for your current shell, of course.

Comment: @ikegami Or better yet, use the list form of [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html), e.g. `system 'bash', '-c', 'command...'`.

Comment: @JB_User Ash is [Almquist shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almquist_shell), Dash is [Debian Almquist shell](http://gondor.apana.org.au/~herbert/dash/), Bash is [Bourne Again SHell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/). You may occasionally find systems that use [KornShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KornShell),
 [Bourne Shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell) or others. If you only use [POSIX features](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html) they should all work. In practice you should at least check Bash and ash.

Comment: Okay.  Thanks for explaining the shell names.  Here's what I'm looking for.  How can I tell if this Perl command system("xterm >& /dev/null &") will work on a system?  Right now I know of one system where it works, and one where it doesn't.  What key feature determines whether the next machine I log into can use one form of syntax, but not another???

Comment: @JB_User If the system has Bash installed as `/bin/sh` then `>&/dev/null` will work (although I still recommend using `&>/dev/null` in Bash). If another shell is installed as `/bin/sh` it will likely not work. [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html) says nothing about shell syntax for redirecting stdout and stderr at the same time, so you should not be using this syntax in a portable script.

Comment: Okay, I get it.  /bin/sh is actually a symbolic link to either dash, bash, or whatever else.  That's what I was missing.  Thanks for responding!

Comment: @JB_User It's also possible that it is simply "whatever else" without being a symbolic link (e.g. on Solaris).